# EmptyThrowable: Unexpected template constraint: NOEMPTY

Tags: android, android-studio

My AndroidStudio stop working and throw an error in Event Log

```
 EmptyThrowable
 Unexpected template constraint: NOEMPTY.
 Expected one or more of: (UNIQUE|EXISTS|NONEMPTY|EMPTY|ACTIVITY|APILEVEL|CLASS|PACKAGE|APP_PACKAGE|MODULE|LAYOUT|DRAWABLE|VALUES|ID|SOURCE_SET_FOLDER|STRING|URI_AUTHORITY)
```

[image]

I have tried to clean project, restart AndroidStudio but it still not work

Comment: have you added any third party template to your `Android Studio`?

Answer (score 1):

i too faced the same problem
This is cause by 2 reasons
1- VCS
2- version

i solved this way

Click on **File -> settings -> Version Control**

Double Click on Version control and you can see file path
At the top of that you can see as like in image
[select none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptTeA.jpg)

There select none and this will disable VCS and it will go fine

Finally Indexing
**File -> Invalidate Cashes / Restart**

If you want VCS you have not committed the code. If this is the case, then commit the code and you get solved.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with your template. To solve that you can try this:

Go to this path:

`<AndroidStudio-Home>/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities`

for Mac:

`/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities`

Then you will find various folders for respective activities. Go to that folder which you selected while creating project. Suppose you selected `EmptyActivity` while creating your project then go to `EmptyActivity` folder and you will find `template.xml` file. Open it and check if there is some value with `NOEMPTY` as a string.

You just need to replace your `NOEMPTY` with `NONEMPTY` and you are done.
Hope It will help you.